# How do I sort with multiple conditions on python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
6 7 5 2 12
0 2 3 6 12
2 8 5 4 13
4 3 5 7 14


 def getMinIndex(list, start, stop):
    n=len(list)
    min_index = start
    for i in range(start,stop):
        if list[i][4] > myList[min_index][4]:
            min_index = i
    return min_index

def swapElements(list,i,j):
    temp = list[i]
    list[i] = list[j]
    list[j] = temp
```

With this code I manage to sort the last element on the list which is index 4 but I'm having problem to sort the 1st index as I want the results to be like this.

```
0 2 3 6 12
6 7 5 2 12
2 8 5 4 13
4 3 5 7 14
```

So if the last element is the same after sorting then I want to sort the 1st element. Can anyone help? Thanks :D

Comment: what is the data structure of your input / output? Is it a list of lists?

Comment: You should avoid re-naming built-ins like `list`... Try using `my_list` or `arr` instead. That `len(list)` line would normally raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is a *key function* for items on your list. Let me illustrate with an example.

## Sorting keys

Suppose you have a list of people. You want to sort them by height. You can't just sort them using `sorted` because they aren't comparable by default the way numbers are. You need to specify the key used for sorting. The key is the characteristic you want to sort on. In this case it could look like:

```
sorted(people, key=lambda person: person.height)
```

or, if you find the lambda notation confusing:

```
def get_height(person):
    return person.height

sorted(people, key=get_height)
```

## Sorting tuples

A tuple is a finite sequence of items: `(2,3)` (2-tuple or pair), `(-3, 2, 1)` (3-tuple) and so on. Tuples are sorted alphabetically automatically. You don't need to do anything.

What's special in your case is that you don't want to sort by the first element, then by the second, and so on. You want to sort by the fourth and then by the first.

This is where keys enter the scene.

## Tying it all together

You need a key function that will turn `(a, b, c, d, e)` into `(e, a)` which means: sort by the fifth column first and then by the first one:

```
def sorting_key(item):
    return (item[4], item[0])
```

Then you can just call:

```
sorted(items, key=sorting_key)
# or with a lambda
sorted(items, key=lambda item: (item[4], item[0]))
```

## Getting the index corresponding to a minimum

I noticed that your function returns a minimum corresponding to the element. You can sort the whole thing and take the first element. Alternatively, you can use the built-in `min` function and provide it the sorting key.

The only thing you need to take into account is that `min` returns the corresponding *value*, not the index. You can work around this with:

```
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(items), key=lambda (index, value): (value[4], value[0]))
```

`enumerate` pairs list items with their indexes so `[a, b, c]` becomes `[(0, a), (1, b), (2, c)]`. Then you sort these pairs as if the indexes weren't present: `key` accepts `index` as the first argument in a tuple but *ignores it completely*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) and use it for a custom sorting key function which you can pass to one of the built-in sort functions:

```
> from operator import itemgetter
> lst = [
    [2, 8, 5, 4, 13], 
    [6, 7, 5, 2, 12], 
    [4, 3, 5, 7, 14],
    [0, 2, 3, 6, 12]
  ]
# use tuple of last and first elmnt as sorting key
> sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(-1, 0))  
  [
    [0, 2, 3, 6, 12], 
    [6, 7, 5, 2, 12], 
    [2, 8, 5, 4, 13], 
    [4, 3, 5, 7, 14]
  ]
```